# C++ decltype from enum value

Tags: c++, templates

I have an existing code base which uses an old style enum to label a type:

```
enum value_type {
    FLOAT = 1,
    DOUBLE = 2,
    INT = 3
};
```

I would then like to instantiate `std::vector<T>`based on the enum value - i.e. something like:

```
auto make_vector( value_type enum_value ) -> decltype(std::vector<decltype( enum_value )>) {
   ...
}
```

Of course the `decltype(enum_value)` does not work - what I would want something like the moral equivalent of:

```
if (enum_value == FLOAT)
   return decltype(double());

if (enum_value == DOUBLE)
   return decltype(float());   

...
```

is something like this at all possible - without resorting to the `if (enum_value == )` style of programming?

Comment: Interesting question (imho). you're skirting compile-time with run-time, and I don't think that's going to pan out like you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what I would want something like the moral equivalent of [...] is something like this at all possible - without resorting to the if (enum_value == ) style of programming?

It's not possible if you pass `enum_value` as argument (run-time known) to `make_array()`.

C++ is a static typed language, so the compiler must decide compile-time the return type of the function, so the compiler must known compile-time the `enum_value`.

To solve this problem, you can pass the `enum_value` as template parameter.

About the enum/type conversion, it seems to me that you need something as follows

```cpp
template <value_type>
struct getType;

template <> struct getType<FLOAT>  { using type = float; };
template <> struct getType<DOUBLE> { using type = double; };
template <> struct getType<INT>    { using type = int; };
```

Now you can write a `make_vector()` function as follows

```
template <value_type enum_value>
auto make_vector ()
   -> std::vector<typename getType<enum_value>::type>
 { return {}; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't necessarily need enum and can use tag types you can use tag dispatch overloading:

```
struct float_type_tag {} FLOAT;
struct int_type_tag {} INT;

std::vector<int> make_vector(int_type_tag);
std::vector<float> make_vector(float_type_tag );
```